# Using the revalidate method

Tags: java

So, I now understand why `frame.setVisible(true);` must be done only after all the drawing has been done. An alternative to this, i.e. if more drawing is done after the `setVisible` method is called is to use the `revalidate` method. But is this method to be used on the frame object or the component object?

Comment: Note that, typically, little bits of code (i.e. 'frame.setVisible(true)') are formatted with backticks around them (`\`frame.setVisible(true)\``), to make it clear that they're code.

Answer (score 0):

`Container#revalidate` is to be called, not suprisingly, by the `Container` (frames, panels, etc). Basically this lays out its subcomponents once again. Any changes to a layout related information will automatically invalidate the `Container`which will need to be revalidated to display the components correctly.

Just note that validating a container may be a time consuming operation so its not a good idea to call it unnecessarily.

Also, I wouldnt say `setVisible` must be called after all the drawing has been done as the drawing per se (methods like `paintComponent`) will be done only once the frame is visible. What really matters is if the container has already been laid out or not.